# What is this white contraption attached to the wall?

Tags: identify-this

My dad's staying at a hotel in the US, and forwarded me the picture beneath. What is it?

[image]

Comment: Is this even on topic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is an [infrared movement sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_infrared_sensor).

It will switch the light on when it sees movement in the room.
There is an explicit touch-switch in the lower area, if you tap it, it toggles the light  on/off.

Comment: They are mostly used to [reduce air conditioning/heating](https://www.inncom.com/catalog/category/motion-sensors-door-switches) when the room is vacant.

Comment: It's full of these in Romania in many public institutions.

Comment: @StefanS - I'd say these are common worldwide!

Comment: I normally see these as part of a burglar alarm system.

Comment: Thanks. (1) My dad couldn't feel the switch? (2) Is this sensor battery-operated? How'd it work without power?

Comment: (1) there is no mechanical switch. You need tap it once quickly. (2) it's connected to the power in the back. Note that it could be broken.

Comment: They're also called PIR sensors (Passive Infra-Red)